# Keras: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am a beginner with Keras. I am using a simple dataset here with 20 features for a regression model. I keep getting the error that expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 for the conv2d layer. This is my code:

```
def buildreg():
    regressor=Sequential()
    regressor.add(Dense(units=170,input_dim=20))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=25))
    regressor.add(Conv1D(16,5))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=100))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=55))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=10))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=60))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_absolute_error')
    return regressor
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=buildreg,batch_size=15,epochs=20)
```

The input is a dataframe with 20 features. The dataset is a very small one around 1k rows. I am fully aware of the fact that it will overfit. Properly processed. Data works just fine with MLPRegressor.

Comment: Why do you pass the output of Dense layer into Conv?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I just wanted to try out different combinations. Should I not be doing that?

Comment: Generally, Conv layer comes before dense, as you might have already lost some sequential patterns with dense before conv.

Comment: Okay. I tried that just now. Still getting the same error.

Comment: What's your input? What are its dimensions?

Comment: Yes. It's a regression problem. The input is a dataframe with 20 features. All are float64 and int64

Comment: Can you share the sample data

Comment: Train: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ziLS1OWu7FXQxq-7LzroFnCTUg4l2Ja0/view?usp=sharing
Labels: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ui3uEw7EggK6R1SyQpCtT2UsBhJxheMw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Since each of the features are independent, you can use dense layer directly. Remove the conv layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you would like to use Conv1D then use Conv1D as first layer and specify input_shape as below

```
input_shape=(N_features, 1)
```

and also reshape your train to shape (nb_of_examples, nb_of_features, 1).

So, your modified code will look like this,

```
Processed--XTRAIN = Processed--XTRAIN.reshape(1457,20,1)

def buildreg():
    regressor=Sequential()
    regressor.add(Conv1D(16,5,input_shape=(20, 1)))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=170,input_dim=20))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=25))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=100))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=55))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=10))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=60))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_absolute_error')
    return regressor
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=buildreg,batch_size=15,epochs=20)
```

2)Else, you can remove the convolution layer and the build simple ANN model. Just use the Dense layer to build your model.

Your code will look something like this

```
def buildreg():
    regressor=Sequential()
    regressor.add(Dense(units=170,input_dim=20))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=25))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=100))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=55))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=10))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=60))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_absolute_error')
    return regressor
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=buildreg,batch_size=15,epochs=20)
```